# R Losing Precision of Decimal Points When Reading/Writing CSV?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, decimal, truncate

I am reading in data with R using `read_csv` from the `readr` package. I have precise time values down to the tenth of a second that are in the following format: `2018-12-30T21:25:32.200`, with everything up to `T` being the date, and everything after being time in HH:MM:SS:fraction-of-a-second format.

However, when assigning this to a variable with `read_csv`, when printed it is reformatted and truncated to just `2018-12-30 21:25:32 UTC`. I'm not sure where the UTC is coming from, or where my fraction of a second is going. When I write this data back to csv using `write_csv`, the result is the following: `2018-12-30T21:25:32Z`. How can I prevent my data from getting cut off? The fraction of a second data is critical to my project.

Comment: You haven't shown us how you specified the input format.  If you are using `format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS"` for the conversion on input, then the fractional seconds should be stored, but not displayed.  You can get them to display by using the format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3" for output.

Comment: Look at your values with `dput`. That will let you avoid the common error of assuming that print-to-console output is complete. Also R times are stores at UTC. You need to study the help page `?DateTimeClasses` and you need to offer a complete example since saying "write this data back to csv" has no code to give it specificity.

Comment: From `?write_csv`: *"POSIXct's are formatted as ISO8601 with a UTC timezone _Note: 'POSIXct' objects in local or non-UTC timezones will be converted to UTC time before writing._"*. I'm not a pro on [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), but it does not *mandate* sub-seconds; while I share your frustration at silent truncation, I suggest you should instead convert it to a string yourself if you need to control sub-second resolution in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `digits.secs` options to both see and write the milliseconds properly:

```
# Create test data
f <- file("test.csv", open = "w")
writeLines("MyPreciseTime", con = f)
writeLines("2018-12-30T21:25:32.200", con = f)
writeLines("2018-12-30T21:25:32.201", con = f)
writeLines("2018-12-30T21:25:32.202", con = f)
close(f)

library(readr)

# Input format not specified but milliseconds still stored
df <- read_csv("test.csv")

# Set the options for digits.secs
options(digits.secs = 3)

# Now print will show the milliseconds
print(df$MyPreciseTime, usetz = FALSE)
# [1] "2018-12-30 21:25:32.200" "2018-12-30 21:25:32.200"
# [3] "2018-12-30 21:25:32.201"
```

Note that if the `digits.secs` option is set appropriately, `write_csv()` will use the specified precision when writing the times back out.  Normally it writes with no milliseconds.  So this is a valuable option when working with precise times.